# CSS position:sticky stack two elements within a div

Tags: html, css, header, sticky

I will try to explain my problem in a way that is as clear as possible.

We are using a ERP that is web-based and when you access a Sale Order document you get to see a form view with a status bar in the top (which shows the current status of the document and also some buttons to perform some actions) and a table with the sale order lines within the document.

[image: Status Bar]

[image: Quotation table with the sale order lines]

The problem is that some quotations are too big and the header of the table gets lost when scrolling down. I'm facing a lot of trouble try to get the header of a table stuck at the top using CSS only.

Here's a snippet of the source code:

[image: div o_content area]

If I set the header position to sticky and scroll down, what I get is this:

[image: Header underneath statusbar]

As you can see, it is underneath the statusbar. I'd like it to stick to it. But I don't see how would I define a div that goes from the bottom of the status bar to the end of the view so the header sticks in there.

I know I can set the "top" property of the header to the exact height of the status bar but this one can change if there's a lot of content on it, that's it, it's a dynamic height.

Here's the div structure:

[image: Div structure]

I can provide a html file if needed.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you use JS? If so, you can grab the dynamic height of the element and adjust the top position of the table.

Comment: Hello amar! Thank your for your quick answer. I can use JS, but the thing is that when I change the "top" value of the header, the table doesn't look well. I mean, I saw that with top = 17 px the look when stuck at the top was the desired, but when the header was in the mid of the view it was displaced to the bottom. I can add a picture if you need it.